# Having trouble using the using the photoshop api with Python to make the blue channel of an image completely white

Tags: python, image-processing, photoshop, photoshop-script

new to the site and beginner level user of Python. I am attempting to automate this process for the use of editing normal maps. Setting the blue channel to black or white makes it compatible/incompatible for certain games/programs. There are many similar questions regarding the editing of channels of an image, but none specifically pertain to setting a channel to any specific color. Also to clarify, I am not looking to simply invert the image either. This is because some blue channels of normal maps have black and white pixels, so inverting would not solve the issue.

```
import glob
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import photoshop.api as PS
from photoshop import Session
```

```
def Automate():

    app = PS.Application('version 23')

    
    for file in glob.glob(values['TARGET_FOLDER']):

         with Session() as ps:
    
             ps.app.load(file)
             doc = ps.active_document
```

I've gotten to the point where I can open up PS and load a file. This was a good start. However, I have not been able to edit the blue channel of the file through any means involving the original api library. Is there a way to edit the blue channel filling it completely with the color White, using this library or any other library such as Pillow?

Comment: Try to use `im.split` to get each rgb bands, create a new blue band by `Image.new` with white or black color, then `Image.merge` R, G and new B bands. (Library Pillow).

Comment: Getting another ValueError: mode mismatch. Used `r,g,b,a = image.split()` and then `b= Image.new('RGBA', image.size, (0,0,0))`. The error occurs on merging. `Image.merge('RGBA', (r,g,b,a))` I have a save method after that but it doesn't get to that point yet.

Comment: Check the b.mode before you call Image.new. The mode and color of the band b should not be the rgba and (0, 0, 0). Maybe 'L' and 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use im.split to get each rgb bands, create a new blue band by Image.new with white or black color, then Image.merge R, G and new B bands. (Library Pillow).

Example code

```py
from PIL import Image

im = Image.new('RGBA', (10, 10), (255,255,255,255))
r, g, b, a = im.split()
b = Image.new('L', (10, 10), 0)
new = Image.merge('RGBA', (r, g, b, a))
new.show()
```

Comment: This is excellent. Changing b.mode to 'L' instead of 'RGBA' made it work as it should. Thanks for the assist Jason.